# Disable onselect() event using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010

I am using a html input text and i want to disable the onselect() event. i have tried the following but with no luck:

```
*onselect="event.returnValue=false";

*onselect="return false";

*onselect="prevent(event)" with a event.preventDefault()
```

is there anyway ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a global boolean variable which can be set from outside. You can set this boolean variable with another element to "disable" your onselect event.

in head, you put this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var eventEnabled=true;

function onSelectEvent() {
  if (!eventEnabled) {
    return;
  }
  //do other things
}
<script>
```

in body: you should have a component which sets the "eventEnabled" variable, like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Disable Event" onclick="eventEnabled=false;" />
```

Furthermore, you have something like onSelect="onSelectEvent();", which you never change.

Comment: OK, edited my post and added a small code, at least for the head part.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
onselect = function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling onselect event why dont you use readonly property of the input tag ??
You may achieve what you desire..